# Linq databinding issue....data doesnt show up in gridview ...I get the message that number and name field are not found in the data source

Tags: linq

```
List<Emp> employees = new List<Emp>();
        Emp e1 = new Emp();
        e1.number = 2;
        e1.name = "Dinesh";
        employees.Add(e1);
        Emp e2 = new Emp();
        e2.number = 3;
        e2.name = "Vishal";
        employees.Add(e2);

        var query = from n in employees
                    orderby n.name descending
                    select n;

        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Code works fine for me. Can you please edit your post to include GridView1 markup? Whether you are using TemplateFields or BoundFields could make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to debug the situation as possibly some settings in GridView are not exactly matching DataSource.

Easily you could bind your grid in design time to type Emp, which would generate all the columns for you:

In YourGridFile.Designer.cs add:

```
 this.GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
 this.GridView1.DataSource = typeof(Emp);
```

somewhere before ResumeLayout lines.

Then you will be able to compare what you have set up manually and what should be in columns definitions.

Comment: Upon adding typeof(Emp), I get the following message:-
Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Comment: I think @too debugging suggestion should read typeof(List<Emp>)

Comment: -1: 1. don't put code in .designer.cs files, 2. as the error message says, you can only assign instances of something IEnumerable to the DataSource property. This means, not "typeof(List<Emp>)" either. See JumpingJezza's comment.